# Zend Framework 1 - do not display trailing slash in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

I know there are various questions out there and various solutions on how to achieve this via .htaccess

The question is simple - when a user enters a url like

```
www.abc.com/users/index/
```

It should appear as

```
www.abc.com/users/index
```

I read somewhere that using htaccess for this purpose is an overkill and it should be done in the predispatch or preprocess method in Zend.

I am not sure how that can be done.

Has anyone done this without using .htaccess

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that .htaccess is an overkill. Running entire application (to predispatch) is quite expesive.

But to answer your question: extend the Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

In preDispatch method you can check the URL: $request->getRequestUri();

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Add this code in your .htaccess file and check if it's working for you or not.

Comment: Thanks Jalpa - this still does not prevent the user from entering slash at the end